# Is there a common message protocol for sensor data on top of MQTT-SN?

Tags: sensor, data, protocol, units, mqtt

I want to communicate various sensor data in a network of sensors.

I found [MQTT and MQTT-SN](http://mqtt.org/documentation) as suitable protocols for that. The latter being better suited for sensor networks with support for sleeping devices, predefined communication, alternatives to TCP, etc. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29083422)

However, both are payload agnostic. The message sent can be of arbitrary format and content. **Is there a common format specifically for sensor data with small footprint?**

I'd like to communicate a measurement value of a specified unit and dimensionality. Maybe with a specified tolerance/expected error.
I could come up with a custom format and just shove it into the payload, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel and rather use existing formats if any exist. That would also ensure compatibility to other networks that use this format.

I found

- [an experimental proposal for an extension to XMPP](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0323.html#glossary) which supports things like `Unit` or `Timestamp`. However, the overhead of the format being XML based makes it undesirable for my application.

  ```
  <message from='device@example.org'
           to='client@example.org/amr'>
     <fields xmlns='urn:xmpp:iot:sensordata' seqnr='1' done='true'>
        <node nodeId='Device01'>
           <timestamp value='2013-03-07T16:24:30'>
              <numeric name='Temperature' momentary='true' automaticReadout='true' value='23.4' unit='°C'/> 
           </timestamp>
        </node>
     </fields>
  </message>
  ```
- [Home Assistant](https://home-assistant.io/components/sensor.mqtt/), which specifies a format that also has `unit_of_measurement` and `value_template`. But this is more about extracting data from arbitrary MQTT messages into a format of the platform instead of specifying a format for the MQTT message itself. In fact, people write extensions to use [JSON in the MQTT message](https://github.com/corbanmailloux/esp-mqtt-rgb-led)

Is there simply no such thing as a standard (or at least common) lightweight message format for sensor data?

Answer (score 1):

[Media Types for Sensor Markup Language (SENML)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-jennings-senml-10) may be interesting for you.

[Chapter 6.1.1.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-jennings-senml-10#section-6.1.1) gives you an example:

> {"e":[{ "n": "urn:dev:ow:10e2073a01080063", "v":23.5 }]}

Comment: Looks like [this](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-core-senml-04#section-11.1) is the most recent version. I was scared away at first when seeing JSON format, but there's also EXI which looks rather compact and suitable for embedded. It looks like there are only a few libraries out there for this.